# Laravel get data from db array not working

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, laravel-blade

When I run the code I get no error but the data I am trying to display is not displaying it's just blank.. can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My controller:

```
public function openingPage($id) {

      $this->getGames();
      $games = $this->getGames();

      return view('caseopener')->with('games',$games);

    }

private function getGames() {
      $games = array();
      foreach ($this->data->items as $item) {
          $game = new Game($item);
          $games[] = array(
                'id' => $game['id'],
                'name' => $game['name'],
                'price' => $game['price'],
                'image' => $game['image'],
            );

      }

      return $games;
  }
```

The '**Game**' Model that is used in 'getGames function':

```
class Game extends Model
{
  private $id;
  public $data;

  public function __construct($id) {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->data = $this->getData();
   }

   private function getData() {

       $game = DB::table('products')->where('id', 1)->first();

       if(empty($game)) return array();

       return $game;
   }
}
```

The view:

```
@foreach ($games as $game)

    <div class="gold">$ {{ $game['price'] }}</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: first() returns only an object

Comment: Does `$this->data->items` contain anything? Does `$item` contain anything?

Comment: Yes it contains this `private function getCaseData($id) {
        $items = DB::table('cases')->where('id', $id)->get();
        $data = @$items[0] ? $items[0] : array();
        if(isset($data->items)) {
            $data->items = json_decode($data->items, true);
        }`

Comment: Did you try to `dd($this->data->items)` or `dd($item)`?

Comment: I believe that `$game = DB::table('products')->where('id', 1)->first();` Is always looking for the game with id 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things. You could simplify your flow like this:

Given your provided code, it seems like you are using a custom table name (`'products'`) in your `Game` model. So we'll address this first:

**Game.php**

```
class Game extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products'; //
}
```

Now, it seems like you're searching an array of `Game` ids (`$this->data->items`). If so, you could make use of Eloquent for your query, specially the [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein) method:

**YourController.php**

```
public function openingPage($id)
{
    $games = Game::whereIn('id', $this->data->items)->get();

    return view('caseopener')->with('games', $games);
}
```

Optionally, if you want to make sure of just returning the `id`, `name`, `price` and `image` of each `Game`/product, you could format the response with [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources):

```
php artisan make:resource GameResource
```

Then in your newly created class:

**app/Http/Resources/GameResource.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class GameResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'image' => $this->image,
        ];
    }
}
```

So now just update your controller:

**YourController.php**

```
use App\Http\Resources\GameResource;

public function openingPage($id)
{
    $games = Game::whereIn('id', $this->data->items)->get();

    return view('caseopener')->with('games', GameResource::collection($games));
} //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```